# Chrome - how to submit by javascript a form having input name=submit?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I run into absolutely wierd Chrome's behavoir. Below is the code

```
<form method="post" id="form" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/lalala">
<input type="submit"  />
<input type="text" name="submit" value="Post this" />
</form>

<script>
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        var forma = document.getElementById("form");
        console.log(forma.submit);
        forma.submit(); 
    },30000);
</script>
```

it prints to Chrome debug window

```
<input type="text" name="submit" value="Post this">
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

i.e. document.getElementById("form").submit is an input, but not submit callback!!

Is it possible to submit this form keeping input name=submit?

Comment: Try `document.forms["form"].submit()`

Answer (score 1):

> > Is it possible to submit this form keeping input name=submit?

I believe, the answer is **NO**.

> > I run into absolutely wierd Chrome's behavoir.

I could find the problem in **Firefox** too.

The moment you use the key word `submit` as either the `name` or `id` of an element  within a `form`, the `form.submit` turns in to an `object` referring the **corresponding node** instead of the `function` to `submit` the `form`.

Please refer the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarbbottam/t9w1nsz4/)

```
<form method="post" id="form" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/lalala">
    <input type="submit" />
    <input type="text" name="submit" value="Post this" />
</form>


var form = document.getElementById("form");
console.log(typeof form.submit);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I've found the solution:

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" />
<script>
var button = document.getElementById("submit");
button.click();
</script>
```